# Unable to play media with vlc ocx

Tags: c#, media-player, vlc, ocx

I want to embed the vlc media player in a .NET application I've found a lot of solutions

1. VLC .Net interface <- didn't work with me
2. wrappers for dll functions <>
3. http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com this is nice
4. the activex of VLC - i really liked to use it it must be less bugs and errors but errors found

I found 2 controls "VLC ActiveX plugin and IE web plugin v1" , "VLC ActiveX plugin and IE web plugin v2"
What is the difference between them??
i dragged and dropped the fist one and used the following code

```
axVLCPlugin1.addTarget(@"D:\video\English\10,000.b.c\10000bc.rmvb", null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListAppendAndGo, -666);
axVLCPlugin1.play();
```

that had no effect
i dragged and dropped the second one and used the following code

```
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(@"D:\video\English\10,000.b.c\10000bc.rmvb");
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
//i also tried this
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(0);
```

also it had no effect

I didn't found many details and documentations of the VLC OCX
what is the error ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [v1 of the ActiveX is deprecated](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX) and [v2 is primarily for browser integration](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin) thus not intended to be used like you tried...

Use http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/ - this is a well-working library...

Comment: thank you very much. but i used vlcdotnet and it worked fine . there is no solution for the activex?

Comment: @Ahmedsafan I don't know of a solution with the ActiveX... why do you want to use the ActiveX ?

Comment: Ok I thought it would better but that was wrong I'll use vlcdotnet instead.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the file format. I also tried to use these two ActiveX controls to play media files in a MFC application. It worked with .avi and mp3 format, did not work with mp4 format. And if I remember it correctly, VLC does not have the codecs for .rmvb format in itself by default because of some copyright problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: you need an uri, not a normal path

This:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"D:\video\English\10,000.b.c\10000bc.rmvb");
var converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(converted);
```

There you go.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin (v1 and v2) works fine in c#.net. v2 is better.

You need to use `"file:///"` before the link:

```
axVLCPlugin1.addTarget(@"file:///D:\video\English\10,000.b.c\10000bc.rmvb", null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListAppendAndGo, -666);
```