# Media Player won't do anything

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, media-player, vlc

My code looks to be right, but when I press button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Code below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("C:\Users\Adminx\Downloads\The_Hobbit_Full_Length_Trailer_2_HD.mp4")

        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Also in my `toolbox` the `vlc` things are written in Chinese. Is it meant to look like that (look at picture below)

[image]

Comment: Can you play the file in the vlc player?

Comment: yes, it doesn't do anything no matter what file I use

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` downloading pirated movies? See this for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709277/unable-to-play-media-with-vlc-ocx

Comment: Read the end of the link-
Its a trailer

C:\Users\Adminx\Downloads\The_Hobbit_Full_Length_Trailer_2_HD.mp4

Comment: how do I use those libraries?

Comment: I even tried to do this in vmware on a fresh windows 7 and a fresh vlc and microsoft visual studio express 2012. And this still won't do anything (the vlc items in the toolbox still appear in chinese)

Comment: I am also facing the China name of the VLC ActiveX. I tried it under MS Win 8 & VS 2010 & VS 2012 no matter it is always China's symbols. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured what I was doing wrong

I needed to change:
AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("C:\Users\Adminx\Downloads\The_Hobbit_Full_Length_Trailer_2_HD.mp4")

To this:
AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///C:/Users/Adminx/Downloads/The_Hobbit_Full_Length_Trailer_2_HD.mp4")

Comment: Just wanted to point out with the newest VLC Version 3.x I used this code `var uri = new Uri(@"C:\test\Amex.mov");
            var convertedURI = uri.AbsoluteUri;   axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(convertedURI);`  But it may still be possible to use `file:///...` also?